# AWS RDS for SQL Server - how to create startup stored proc?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are moving to RDS and one of our apps needs access to tempdb and I am trying to figure out the best way to create a startup job that works with RDS.  Currently we are able to create a stored proc that sets up the necessary permissions in the master database and use the `EXEC sp_procoption 'AddPermissionsToTempDb', 'startup', 'true'` command to set it to start at boot.

In RDS however we are not able to create stored procs in the master database.  I tried creating the stored proc in a user-owned db but when I then try to create the startup job with `EXEC sp_procoption 'mydb.dbo.AddPermissionsToTempDb', 'startup', 'true'` it says it can't find the stored procedure or I do not have permission...  Is there another way to accomplish this on RDS?

Comment: You could try scheduling a job with [SQL Server Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html), that runs at agent startup time (`sp_add_jobschedule` with `@freq_type` set to `64`). Disclaimer: I have no idea if this actually works. If it does it would have the benefit of making visible what's running at startup; startup procs aren't very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to find a solution based on [Jeroen Mostert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248055/aws-rds-for-sql-server-how-to-create-startup-stored-proc#comment111841807_63248055) so credit goes to them.  Here is the full query I used to create the startup job to grant permissions to a list of users to create, control and execute stored procedures on tempdb on an AWS RDS SQL Server instance:

```
USE msdb
go

declare @job_name varchar(50)
set @job_name = 'AddTempDBPermissionsOnStartup'

exec dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name =  @job_name

declare @sql varchar(max)
select @sql = '
Declare @Users Table (username varchar(100) )
insert @Users(username) values (''[user1]''),
(''[user2]''),
(''[user3]'')

use tempdb
CREATE ROLE sp_executor GRANT EXECUTE TO sp_executor
CREATE ROLE sp_manipulator 
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO sp_manipulator
GRANT CONTROL TO sp_manipulator

DECLARE @username as NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE User_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT * from @Users
OPEN User_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM User_Cursor INTO @username;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        PRINT @username
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [tempdb].sys.database_principals WHERE type_desc = ''SQL_USER'' AND name = @username)
        PRINT ''  - user already exists''
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT ''  - creating user''
            DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @Sql =
            ''USE Tempdb'' + char(13) + 
            ''CREATE USER '' + @username + '' FOR LOGIN '' + @username  + char(13) +
            ''EXEC sp_addrolemember sp_executor, '' + @username + char(13) +
            ''EXEC sp_addrolemember sp_manipulator, '' + @username
            EXEC (@Sql)
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM User_Cursor INTO @username;
END;
CLOSE User_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE User_Cursor;
GO
'


--Add a job
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = @job_name ;

--Add a job step to run the command
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = @job_name,
    @step_name = N'job step',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = @sql

--Schedule the job to run at startup
exec sp_add_jobschedule @job_name = @job_name,
@name = 'RunAtStartSchedule',
@freq_type=64

 --Add the job to the SQL Server Server
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = @job_name
```